# twig load data from content into field.html.twig

Tags: twig, drupal-8

```
<div class="quote">
<span{{ attributes }}>
  {%- for item in items -%}
    {{ item.content }}
  {%- endfor -%}
</span>
</div>
```

I tried..

**{{ content.field_content_1| Body }}** - this errors out

I'm trying to pull in the:
Quotes (Field)  / field_content_1   / Entity reference

Comment: Do you mean within your for loop using the `item`? Your question and code is not very clear...

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the loop, but I'm really not sure how to pull field_content_1 into the twig template

Comment: Is `content` an Entity or an attribute? If it is an Entity, does the `content` Entity have any getters? Like maybe `getFieldContent`?

Comment: Did you see my last comment?

Comment: Yes, I actually figured out my problem.  I wasn't setting the {{ content.field_content_1}} in the correct template level so nothing was showing up.